# What is the simplest control to stabilize this system (a scholar example)

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I want to show a scholar example of a system such that its linearization is not controllable but the system can be stabilized with nonlinear feedback. I am thinking about this one
$$ \begin{aligned} \dot{x}_1 &= x_2^3, \\ \dot{x}_2 &= u, \end{aligned} $$
where $x_1$, $x_2$, and $u$ are scalars, and the goal is to drive the system to the origin.

What is the simplest control that you would propose for this system?

Comment: What have you tried yourself, for example have you tried backstepping? Also wouldn't $\dot{x}=-x$ satisfy your description, since it is not controllable, but is stable? And how do you define "simplest control"?

Comment: I have tried myself to design this example :) My answer was $u=-x_2^3-x_2-x_1$, but as shown by @SampleTime, the term $x_2^3$ can be omitted. Normally we do not discuss controllability for autonomous systems.

Comment: You could interpret it as $\dot{x}=-x+a\,u$ with $a=0$, otherwise another simple example would be the system $\dot{x}=x\,u$, for which $u=-x^2$ would be a "simple" stabilizing controller.

Comment: Thanks, $\dot{x}=xu$ is a nice example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the linearization is not controllable, the nonlinear system can still be stabilized with linear feedback. I propose the control law

$$
u = -x_1 - x_2 \tag{1}
$$

which leads to the closed loop dynamics

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2^3 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_1 - x_2
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

Take the Lyapunov function

$$
V(x) = x_1^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_2^4
$$

It is easy to show that $V$ has a unique minimum at $(0, 0)$ so it is positive definite. The derivative is

$$
\dot{V}(x) = -2 (x_1 + x_2)^2
$$

which is negative semi-definite (zero along the $x_1 = -x_2$ line). If we insert that into $(2)$, we have $\dot{x}_2 = 0$ but $\dot{x}_1 = -x_1^3$, so no solution can stay in the set $\dot{V}(x) = 0$ except $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.

So, by LaSalle, the system is globally asymptotically stabilized by the linear feedback $(1)$.

This is probably also the "simplest" stabilizing control law (linear feedback with both gains being 1), but that depends on your definition of simple.

Comment: Thanks! Note also that it is sufficient to consider $V(x) = x_1^2 + 0.5 x_2^4$ yeilding $\dot{V} = -2x_2^2$, and then the same invariance argument works.

Comment: Your answer destroys my example. :) I was looking for an example that cannot be stabilized by linear feedback. :)

Comment: @Arastas Sorry about that :) I would also be interested whether such systems even exist (I guess so, but I haven't seen an example yet).

Comment: I do not believe there exists a linear stabilizing control law for $\dot{x}=x\,u$, namely $u=-x^2$ does stabilize it.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen That is indeed a nice example!